# QML XmlListModel and car2go xml parsing

Tags: xml, parsing, kml, qml

I fail to parse car2go responses in qml xmllistmodel.

```
<kml xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
        <Document>
                <description>Available CAR2GO Vehicles</description>
                <Style id="car2go">
                        <IconStyle>
                                <Icon>
                                        <href>http://www.car2go.com/default/img/backgrounds/Marker_car2go.png
                                        </href>
                                </Icon>
                                <hotSpot y="0.0" x="0.0" />
                        </IconStyle>
                </Style>
                <Placemark>
                        <name>UL-C5887</name>
                        <description>Sudetenweg, 89075 Ulm<br/>Fuel
                                24<br/>Interior EXCELLENT<br/>Exterior EXCELLENT
                        </description>
                        <styleUrl>#car2go</styleUrl>
                        <ExtendedData>
                                <Data name="fuel">
                                        <value>24</value>
                                </Data>
                                <Data name="interior">
                                        <value>EXCELLENT</value>
                                </Data>
                                <Data name="exterior">
                                        <value>EXCELLENT</value>
                                </Data>
                                <Data name="vin">
                                        <value>WME4513001K154655</value>
                                </Data>
                        </ExtendedData>
                        <Point>
                                <coordinates>10.029,48.4362,0</coordinates>
                        </Point>
                </Placemark>
        </Document>
 </kml>
```

and my code is

```
XmlListModel {
    namespaceDeclarations: "declare namespace ns2='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';declare default element namespace 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'"
    query: "/kml/Document/Placemark"
    XmlRole { name: "plate_number"; query: "name/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "address"; query: "description/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "fuel"; query: "ExtendedData/Data[1]/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "interior"; query: "ExtendedData/Data[2]/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "exterior"; query: "ExtendedData/Data[3]/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "vin"; query: "ExtendedData/Data[4]/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "coordinates"; query: "coordinates/string()" }
}
```

But i do get

Error XPST0003 in file ... syntax error, unexpected NCName, expecting ;
QML XmlRole: invalid query: "name/string()" etc.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second namespace declaration is missing a terminating semicolon.

Replacing

```
namespaceDeclarations: "declare namespace ns2='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';declare default element namespace 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'"
```

with

```
namespaceDeclarations: "declare namespace ns2='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';declare default element namespace 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2';"
```

should fix it.

Comment: What about sorting of the parsed data ? I want to calculate distance of each car2go to coordinates X,Y and show them ascending.